# Data import issue on salesforce

Tags: data-loader, data-import-wizard

I have a data import issue which seems to be odd and i want to confirm the behavior. We are using the data import wizard and trying to import contacts records matching on email id. Here is the format of the file

```
external lid, name, email id
101, john smith, jon@gmail.com
102, john smith jr, jon@gmail.com
```

Now i am using email id to match the record and not the external id and we are doing upsert. You can see both the records have the same email id in this case.

What we find is that the contact always gets the first record which is `john smith` instead of `john smith jr` which is what we want. We have people registering twice using the same email id and we always want to update the most recent record on the contact.

When salesforce matches records for upserting, if if finds duplicates in a file on email id, will it always take the first record and ignore the later records in the file? Have you guys encountered this and if so how do you handle it?

Buyan

Comment: is the first data row supposed to be `gmal.com` or `gmail.com` ?

Comment: @cropredy the first data row is gmail.com . Both records have the same email id.